# Cant upload and store the image to the database by using php

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload, upload

I try to build an upload image system by using php.After testing it,the system echo out"Image is uploaded",but it doesn't shown in database.Here is my code here

upload.php

```
<?php
//connect database
include('config.php');

//file properties
 if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
   $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
}

if(!isset($file)){
    echo "Please select an image";
}
else{
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name =addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $image_size =getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    if ($image_size == FALSE) {
        echo "This is not an image";
    }
    else{
        $insert = "INSERT INTO image(name,picture) VALUES ('$image_name','$image')";

        if(!$insert){
            echo "Problem uploading";
        }
        else {
            $lastid =mysqli_insert_id($con);
            echo "Image Uploaded <p />Your Image :<p /><img src=get.php?id=$lastid>";
        }
    }
}


?>
```

get.php

```
<?php
include ('config.php');

$id = addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);

$image = mysqli_query($con ,"SELECT * FROM image WHERE id=$id");
$image = mysqli_fetch_assoc($image);
$image = $image['picture'];

header("Content-type :image/jpeg");
?>
```

and I clicking the submit button without choosing any files this 2 line of warning is showing up

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in upload.php line 14.
>
> line14 is this $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
>
> Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in in upload.php line 16.
>
> while line 16 is this $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));

Any idea about this?

Comment: Why are you wanting to put images in the database to begin with?

Comment: @MikeBrant what you mean ya??

Comment: I mean that, generally speaking, storing images in a database, rather than a file system reference to an image, is a bad application design. Unless you are doing binary searches on the images themselves or something like that, you are probably saddling yourself with a bad architecture.

Comment: @MikeBrant mike,any reference for me to do the file system reference that you mention??any reference that provided is well-appreciated..Cause i am a very beginner in php languages..tq

Comment: Just store your files in the file system, CDN, or similar and store a path reference to the file in your database.

Comment: means that storing the image in a file first,then only store the particular file to the database?? @MikeBrant

Comment: No. I mean you only store a file reference like /path/to/image.png in the database.

Comment: Just look back the question I ask,now I understand what you mean.thanks..haha

Comment: Sometimes it takes a bit of a learning curve before a concept becomes tangible.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a function to send your query, otherwise you just filled up a string: this:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO image(name,picture) VALUES ('$image_name','$image')";
```

should be followed by this:

```
mysqli_query($con, $insert);
```

The warnings are caused by multiple issues with your code. First you are checking whether the file has been uploaded in the wrong way: this

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
}
```

Will always set a `$file` variable, even though no file has been selected into the form, leading therefore to never execute this if statement:

```
if(!isset($file)){
    echo "Please select an image";
}
```

and to always execute what's in the else block instead, which causes the errors, because the functions you mentioned, which are contained in this else block, are not able to operate on any file.

Therefore simply checking the file upload correctly will solve the issue: one way to do this would be to first remove this, which is unuseful

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
}
```

and then change this:

```
if(!isset($file)){
    echo "Please select an image";
}
```

to this:

```
if(!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){
    echo "Please select an image";
}
```

Comment: then how to handle "mysqli_query($con,$insert)" here?? make an "if/else" statement to compare it or what?mind to explain more about it?? @kos

Comment: You can just compare the function itself like this: if(!mysqli_query($con, $insert)) echo "Problem uploading"; else echo "Image Uploaded <p />Your Image :<p /><img src=get.php?id=$lastid>";

Comment: wow..is work now..the image can insert to the database now..thanks

Comment: but the warning for Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in upload.php line 14.Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in in upload.php line 16. this 2 line of error is still exists..mind to give me some idea?? thanks @kos

Comment: sir,i do what you mention,it cause a error here  Undefined index: image on line 6,line 6 >if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) is on line 6

Comment: Is work,the image can store in database,and can echo out at upload.php here,but just have the error that i mention above..

Comment: let me check on this. this error shows up only when you don't choose a file in the upload form as i understood, right? if thats the case try to change the if condition to !isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']), otherwise let me check on this for a minute, because i'm probably missing something then

Comment: just add the if('$POST'){ at the there,then everything is going smooth..really appreciated of your help..tq

Comment: ok that would probably work anyway, but please do me a favor, can you check !isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) anyway? because i believe that would be a little more proper, and if so i could change my answer for further people who will be looking into this.

Comment: so change the if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) to if(!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) ?? is that what you mean??

Comment: is work also by using if(!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))

Comment: which one will be better??

Comment: if(!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])), because the other way you're just checking if any POST data has been sent. So any input filled in into the form would make isset($_POST) return 1 anyway, while the user could have not selected any image, so this is the only correct way if you have more than 1 input in your form. If you have only one input isset($_POST) it's ok though. It's nice to hear that it helped, I'll change my answer accordingly

Comment: is luckily have you here..i stuck on this for quite a long time ady..thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

After line 16 you need to echo the image data.

echo $image;

@ken, here is a function that I use to output the image by setting the correct headers:

```
    function output_headers($filetype, $imgsize, $filename, $attachment=false)
{
header("Content-Type: {$filetype}");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
$offset = 60 * 60 * 24 * 4 -1;
$ExpStr = "Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $offset) . " GMT";
header($ExpStr);
header("Cache-Control: max-age=$offset");
//header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header("Content-Length: $imgsize");
#insert the filename we want into the image so it can be saved with something
# more meaningful that showimg.jpg. :-)
# 04/03/06
#attachment causes save as to appear, inline serves imbedded image.
if ($attachment)
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
else
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
}
```

This is part of a php file called showimg.php.jpg

This needs to be saved into a separate directory with the following .htaccess file to get php to handle requests for .jpgs:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .jpg
```

In this way, the webpage refers to the image `<img src='/img/showimg.php.jpg?<add your parameters here>`

regards
Steve