# Warning: Illegal string offset 'mime'

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to store images in MySQL and getting the **warning**

> Illegal offset 'mime'

on the following code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db = mysql_select_db("imagestore",$conn);
if(!$db)
{
    echo mysql_error();
}
$rollNo = $_POST['rollNo'];
$image = addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_s=getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$imgtype = $image['mime'];
$q = "INSERT INTO students VALUES('','$rollNo','$image','$imgtype')";
$r=mysql_query($q,$conn);
if($r)
{
    echo "Information stored successfully";
}
else
{
    echo mysql_error();
}
?>
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Where you want to store images ?

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591379/cant-upload-and-store-the-image-to-the-database-by-using-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo. You're using the wrong variable name when getting mime information. Replace $image[mime] with $image_s; getimagesize() offers mime info.

```
$image_s = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$imgtype = $image_s['mime'];
```